# angularJS - background image has gone

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an angularJS function, and to make it works, I added some code to the `html` and `body` tags: `<html lang="en" ng-app="plunker" ng-controller='headController' >`, `<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">`  But after I did it, some css code that I use stopped working, and my background image has gone.

How can I fix it? I don't have much experience with angulatJS, so I will be grateful for an advise.

---

The code I use should change CSS if I press a button,  I'm trying to use this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jBtP6FfmeRzOYUCnHg3t?p=preview

Comment: what do your controller codes look like?

Comment: Please post more code

Comment: add some of your code

Comment: @DavidH. It should change css stylesheet if I press a button: http://plnkr.co/edit/jBtP6FfmeRzOYUCnHg3t?p=preview

Comment: @Chinni Sure, done!

Comment: @Rakeschand Sure, done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{stylePath}}">
```

With

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{stylePath}}">
```

Because href is standard html and does not bind with input therefore not registering changes.

Comment: I just tried it with my code, but it didn't works in my case... the link I sent  you in the commrnts leads to te example of angularjS code I use, but thehtml  page I work with at the moment is more complicated. I need some time to check, if I made some mistake, and your answer works. But thank you very much for the answer!